# Python pyplot scatter is not using colors

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a scatter chart with pandas and matplotlib.pylot.  The dots in the graph are only using one color, while the legend is showing there are three different colors for three different groups of data.

Below is my code and a copy of screen shot. You can see that only all dots are in green color.  Could anyone point me why? What did I do wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'x':[1,2,3,4,1,3,7,5], 
    'y':[10, 20, 30, 40, 20, 30, 40, 80], 
    'label':['A', 'A','B','B','A','C','C','A'] 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
plt.figure(figsize=(34,8))
fig,ax = plt.subplots()


#sns.scatterplot(data=df, hue='label', x='x', y='y')
for k, d in df.groupby('label'):
    ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], label=k)


plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You could use `d` instead of `df` in `ax.scatter(d['x'], d['y'], label=k)` to prevent taking the complete dataframe again and again. Also note that `plt.figure()` here creates an unused empty plot. You can set the `figsize` via `fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much JohanC for your comment.  It  helps me improve the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add colors mapping. Slight modifications to your code after adding colors dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

data = {
    'x':[1,2,3,4,1,3,7,5],
    'y':[10, 20, 30, 40, 20, 30, 40, 80],
    'label':['A', 'A','B','B','A','C','C','A']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#plt.figure(figsize=(34,8))
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

df1 = df.groupby('label')
colors = iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(df1.groups))))

for k, d in df1:
   ax.scatter(d['x'], d['y'], label=k, color=next(colors))


plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

outputs the scatter plot as:
[image: Colorful Scatter Plot]

Is this your desired output?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, is there anyway not specific the color and let system pick them?  The main reason of it is sometime I don't know how many colors I need, or if there are a lot of labels, defining all the colors is kind of tough.

Comment: Updated the code in my answer to dynamically generate colors instead of hard coding. This should scale based on number of labels you end up with.